# How to insert a number from R to LaTeX?

Tags: r, latex

I´m trying to insert a number directly from R into a LaTeX file. I have only been able to do it as a table and that doesn´t allow me to put it in the middle of a sentence.

I would like the output to look like this:

"The final number is [number directly from R]"

What should I do?

Comment: Check out `knitr` http://yihui.name/knitr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the **Sweave** or **knitr** (assuming `.Rnw` file), use `\Sexpr{foo}`. Then run the file through R + Sweave or R + knitr and you'll have a LaTeX source with the value of `foo` inserted in place of `\Sexpr{foo}`.

Basically you need to markup your LaTeX source appropriately, run it through a system using R to identify the things you want to replace and insert the actual data into the source file, and output a LaTeX source which you can then compile.

There are other systems besides Sweave and Knitr so find a system you like that suits your workflows. For example, there is **brew**.